# Break php code execution and continue with next request | multi-request serverside code execution

Tags: php, compiler-construction, interpreter, yield

Is it possible to make php code execution to break at a certain command, end the http connection, than "wait" for the client to request the page again and continue from that point but with new $_POST or $_GET content?

I don't think php offers such a thing because it's hard to make sure the second request comes from the same client.

The usage should be for controlling a simple device over the internet by a program running on the server. The device just recieves some simple commands from the server like `forward` or `turn_left` and responds with statements like `success` or `turning_failed`. But to be able to run the complex code on the server I need the ability to get feedback from the device.

And because the code is complex, I can't have simple solution like indexing the requests or something like that. The "break" command could be inside another function and/or inside a loop...

So the only solution I came up with is to make my own interpreter written in php, which would be able to break execution like required and save all states to a file and later on continue from that point.

So my question should be: **Do you know such a sophisticated interpreter?** (language doesn't matter - c#, lua, js, ...) It would take a long time to make my own so I want to know all options.

Btw, php generators look really nice to me but they are iterable only in foreach loop not in forsomerequest loop :D

Comment: I also thought about that but I can't just count number of already called "breaks" since they could be inside loops. And i can't event save the line of php and than call eval() on the rest of the code since breaks can be inside function calls.

Comment: You can break execution with exceptions. You don't need to have php "wait" to accomplish what you are looking for, either store some state indicator in a database or flatfile, or stash it in the session variable, and then reference the same page again, which should be developed so it is reactive to state params (wherever you store them). Foreach is not your only option for iteration, you should have a gander at: http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php

Comment: You can communicate back and forth with the request and response headers. This is how ajax and most web services work, including in multilevel request situations.